# How do I make this snippet of CoffeeScript TurboLinks 5 friendly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following:

```
$ ->
    $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
      $(this).summernote
        height: 300
```

And this works, however, I would like to make it TurboLinks 5 friendly.

So I tried the following:

```
$ ->
  ready = ->
    $('data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
      $(this).summernote
        height: 300

  $(document).ready(ready)
  $(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ready is not defined
```

How do I fix this so that I make the original snippet TL-5 friendly?

**Edit 1**

By the way, I am doing this in my `jobs.coffee` file, which I know is being included in my asset-pipeline. So that's not it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 5 (Turbolinks 5), `turbolinks:load`. Also, you don't need to wrap your event handlers into the "document ready".

Rewrite your code to this:

```
ready = ->
  $('data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote(height: 300)

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

Comment: Awesome. Perfect. Thanks. I left some more questions I have on the other question, that is related to this answer.