# How do I combine these two snippets of CoffeeScript into 1 file that works?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have two snippets that work independently:

```
$ ->
    $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
      $(this).summernote
        height: 300
```

And this:

```
$ ->
  companySelect = $('#company-select')
  jobFields = $('#job-fields')
  companySelect.change ->
    # if selected option is the first option
    if $(this).find('option:selected').index() == 1
      jobFields.show().find(':input').prop 'disabled', false
    else
      jobFields.hide().find(':input').prop 'disabled', true
    return
  # call change immediately so this still works when already updating and not just creating.
  companySelect.change()
  return
```

Given that these two snippets govern two things within the `Jobs#Views`, I would like to combine them both in my `jobs.coffee` file.

But I am not quite sure how to put both of them in the same file so they both work without interfering with each other.

I tried some stuff, but since I don't really fully understand CoffeeScript I am sure I did it wrong, so that didn't work.

**Edit 1**

Given [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37909264/91970) that @Uzbekjon gave along with his answer to this question, this is what my combined file looks like now:

```
ready = ->
  $('data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote(height: 300)

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)


companySelect = $('#company-select')
  jobFields = $('#job-fields')
  companySelect.change ->
    # if selected option is the first option
    if $(this).find('option:selected').index() == 1
      jobFields.show().find(':input').prop 'disabled', false
    else
      jobFields.hide().find(':input').prop 'disabled', true
    return
  # call change immediately so this still works when already updating and not just creating.
  companySelect.change()
```

I am now getting this error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError at /jobs/new
SyntaxError: [stdin]:10:1: unexpected indentation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to name your file `jobs.js.coffee` (don't forge `js`). Also, spacing/tabs matter, so make sure you don't indent/unindent part of the code.

```
$ ->
  $('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote
      height: 300

  companySelect = $('#company-select')
  jobFields = $('#job-fields')
  companySelect.change ->
    # if selected option is the first option
    if $(this).find('option:selected').index() == 1
      jobFields.show().find(':input').prop 'disabled', false
    else
      jobFields.hide().find(':input').prop 'disabled', true
    return
  # call change immediately so this still works when already updating and not just creating.
  companySelect.change()
```

### Edit 1:

As per your edit and comment. You have unintentional indentation on lines 10 and 11.

```
jobFields = $('#job-fields')
companySelect.change ->
```

Also, you probably want to have that behavior in `ready` callback like this:

```
ready = ->
  # Setup "summernote" editor
  $('data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
    $(this).summernote(height: 300)

  # Company selector
  companySelect = $('#company-select')
  jobFields = $('#job-fields')
  companySelect.change ->
      # if selected option is the first option
      if $(this).find('option:selected').index() == 1
        jobFields.show().find(':input').prop 'disabled', false
      else
        jobFields.hide().find(':input').prop 'disabled', true
      return
    # call change immediately so this still works when already updating and not just creating.
    companySelect.change()

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

Comment: Ok considering your answer in my other question here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37909264/91970 - what might the combined CoffeeScript look like?

Comment: I have updated the question with more details about what I have tried and what's happening now.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much meng!